# Should I increase max_connections in AWS RDS t1-micro for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS t1-micro running MySQL 5.5. It gives me too many connections error. I checked and it allows 34 maximum connections concurrently. What I have read is that i can increase this max value by creating a DB parameter group for this Micro instance.

My confusion is

- Should I increase the max connection value for micro in DB parameter group? or Should i consider upgrading to next RDS level which provides more maximum connections (125)?
- Should I increase max_connections on micro RDS to 125 vs upgrading to RDS small instance?
- Why and What factors should I make the decision on?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Each connection carries the load of per-connection buffers as set by these parameters

- [join_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size)
- [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size)
- [read_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_buffer_size)
- [read_rnd buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_rnd_buffer_size)

Changing the number of connections increases the amount of memory each connection can demand to this : ([join_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size)+[sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size)+[read_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_buffer_size)
+[read_rnd buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_rnd_buffer_size)) X [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)

I have written about these before

- `Jan 03, 2012` : [Understanding mysqltuner Recomendations w/ Unused Catalogs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10091/877)
- `Apr 24, 2012` : [How costly is opening and closing of a DB connection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16973/877)
- `Feb 01, 2013` : [Show processlist / Max concurrent connections seem to max out at 131](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33941/877)

## ANALYSIS

Amazon has to set the number of connections based on each model's right to demand a certain amount of memory and connections

```
MODEL      max_connections innodb_buffer_pool_size
---------  --------------- -----------------------
t1.micro   34                326107136 (  311M)
m1-small   125              1179648000 ( 1125M,  1.097G)
m1-large   623              5882511360 ( 5610M,  5.479G)
m1-xlarge  1263            11922309120 (11370M, 11.103G)
m2-xlarge  1441            13605273600 (12975M, 12.671G)
m2-2xlarge 2900            27367833600 (26100M, 25.488G)
m2-4xlarge 5816            54892953600 (52350M, 51.123G)
```

I wrote about this as well : [When should I think about upgrading our RDS MySQL instance based on memory usage?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25870/877)

This allows Amazon to do the following:

- Charge you for each memory model based on seamless MySQL usage
- Fairly Apportion Resources for MySQL RDS per region
- Shoot yourself in the foot for tampering with per-connection settings

## RECOMMENDATION

Perhaps you should try useing Amazon EC2 where you have no restrictions on access to my.cnf

Answer (score 3):

From RDS Console > Parameter Groups > Edit Parameters,

You can change the value of the max_connections parameter to a custom value.

Comment: what is the maximum limit to set value ?