# Which hardware you suggest?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm completely new to buying a database hosting and I would greatly appreciate your opinion about the following situation. I just created an App and I want to go live this weekend. I want to be prepared as good as possible so I will write some statistics of the database usage I think to see **every 24 hours**.

```
- 20 000 000 inserts into a table which contains 1 bigint, 7 ints and 1 date.
-  5 000 000 updates on above table
- 10 000 000 inserts into mapping table 1 bigint 1 int
-  2 000 000 inserts into table with 3 ints
-  5 000 000 select queries with WHERE pk reference of first table described above
```

I will use the MySQL 5.5 database with all InnoDB tables. At the moment I am thinking about buying a dedicated server with these stats:

```
Intel Xeon E3-1220LV2 2.3GHz
100 Mbps Uplink
4 GB DDR3 Memory
500 GB RAID-1 Drives
10 TB Bandwidth
Up to 5 Dedicated IPs
```

For a price of $140 dollar a month. What do you think, will this be enough? Would it be overkill? You know a better hosting? At the moment I am on a shared webhost ($12 a month) and I get a fifth of the numbers above, but the shared database is really not optimized for innoDB.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64623/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-vermaat-which-hardware-you-suggest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are honestly expecting to have the numbers you say for an all-InnoDB database, you are going to be needing a lot more memory. Here is why:

InnoDB caches data and index pages in the InnoDB Buffer Pool. If you will be doing heavy reads, a large buffer pool is your best friend. Since most people recommend 75-80% of RAM for a dedicated MySQL DB Server, that would about about 3200M (3.2G).

I would go the following (32GB or RAM)

- [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) = 24G
- [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) = 4
- [innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) = 16
- [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) = 16
- [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) = 1

There are too many other aspects for me to just put in the answer. Here are some of my InnoDB posts:

- [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core/5670#5670)
- [How large should be mysql innodb_buffer_pool_size?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size/27341#27341)
- [How do you tune MySQL for a heavy InnoDB workload?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload/1185#1185)
- [Clarification on MySQL innodb_flush_method variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/clarification-on-mysql-innodb-flush-method-variable/1575#1575)
- [Is it safe to use innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/is-it-safe-to-use-innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit-2/12612#12612)
- [My Other InnoDB Posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:877%20%5Binnodb%5D)

Don't forget to tune the per-connection settings and multiply the sum of them by [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) : See my post [Understanding mysqltuner Recomendations w/ Unused Catalogs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/understanding-mysqltuner-recomendations-w-unused-catalogs/10091#10091)

Comment: +1 for now,thanks a lot so far. I did a small update regarding the selects I would use. So that you have a better understanding about the selects vs dml I use.